# Convert data type string to float in DataFrame

Tags: dataframe, julia

I have a data in `string` format, when I use `DataFrame`, it will be in `Substring` format, but I want it in `Float` format. What should I do?

```
x  = defect_positions[1:3]
>>>SubString{String}["4.71801", "17.2815", "0.187765"]    
>>>SubString{String}["17.3681", "17.1425", "6.13644"]     
>>>SubString{String}["0.439987", "0.00231646", "0.404172"]
DataFrame(permutedims(reduce(hcat, x))

x1  x2  x3
SubStrin…   SubStrin…   SubStrin…
1   4.71801 17.2815 0.187765
2   17.3681 17.1425 6.13644
3   0.439987    0.00231646  0.404172
```

How can I convert my DataFrame to float?

Answer (score 0):

`DataFrame` uses the element types of the input collections You should convert your strings to a floating point number type before creating a `DataFrame`. You can parse a string as a floating number type of your choice with `parse`.

```
# we map each `SubString` array in x (`SubString` arrays) 
# and parse each entries as `Float64` by broadcasting `parse`
parsed_x = map(i -> parse.(Float64, i), x) 
DataFrame(permutedims(reduce(hcat, parsed_x)))
```

You may also choose to do the conversion after creating the `DataFrame` with strings.

```
df = DataFrame(permutedims(reduce(hcat, x))
for i in 1:size(df, 2)
   df[i] = parse.(Float64, df[i])
end
df
```

Both methods give

```
│ Row │ x1      │ x2      │ x3       │
│     │ Float64 │ Float64 │ Float64  │
├─────┼─────────┼─────────┼──────────┤
│ 1   │ 4.71801 │ 17.2815 │ 0.187765 │
...
```